# How do you mount a SD card in ubuntu using the exec option

Tags: steam, sd-card, chromebook

So I have mounted my SD card onto Ubuntu but whenever I try to download a game on steam I get the error message: The selected file system does not allow executing files. Please re-mount it with the exec option and then try again. I am also running Ubuntu dual booted with chrome OS if that matters at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

mount it with umask/dmask:

```
/dev/sda    /media/additional_drive_target_dir  ntfs-3g defaults,auto,fmask=0077,dmask=0022,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000   0 1
```